# Create a navigation window in Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, macros, vba

I'm looking to create "Welcome" window of sorts for the database I'm working on. The window would have four buttons. My current issue is with a button that I want to use to open a form I've already created.

The trick is this form is meant to be the input window to a table, so I don't want the form to come pre-populated with any data, it would (if completed) create a new record, but only once the form is completed.

Opening the form isn't the trouble (DoCmd.OpenForm "form name"), what I'm not sure is how to have it open blank.

Comment: Is the form bound to a recordset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "form name",,,,acFormAdd
```

This opens the form to a "new" record.

Comment: Is there a way to have the form open in a window that's just big enough for the form (as opposed to filling the whole pane)? Just a lot of blank real estate with it that big.

Answer (score 1):

If the form is bound to a table, then you can open it to a "new" record but that record is added to the database as soon as the first value is input.  This doesn't fit your requirement of the record being added "only once the form is completed".

If the form is unbound, it's technically already on a blank record but you would have to create some event to save that record to the table.  That event could be the OnClick event of a button, or the AfterUpdate event of a required field (although the OnClick event of a button is probably the proper method 99.999% of the time).

Comment: This is what I've been implementing for the buttons on the "Home" Window (there's a little polish needed on the Save macro to handle adding the record, but nothing I shouldn't be able to work through)